# Batch script to transcode MXF video files using VLC (mac)

Tags: applescript, osx-mountain-lion, vlc, batch-processing, transcode

I thought this morning i found the answer to my big headache, but apparently I'm not smart enough when it comes to coding:
http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=98694

My problem is the following: I'm a video editor and last week both of my drives in my RAID NAS crashed. I have been able to recover 500GB of videos, but lost the index, so all files lost their references and some of then are corrupted and buggy. The only app that is reading them whatever stage they are in is VLC (best player for years BTW).
So it reads all my files and miracle it also have an integrated transcoding wizard that is by far the most qualitative one: when I do an output in .ts with high bitrate compression, i have no quality loss, and above all it read smoothly in premiere CS6, so even if all my my files are all over the shop, somewhere I found a way to recover them, and being able to send them in my video editing programme!!

Only problem VLC doesn't do batch transcoding, and this problem concerns about 3000 video files that needs to be converted from their original (now recovered but corrupted) .MXF to a Hi quality Mpeg.ts (editable in Premiere Pro CS6).

I found in this forum: http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=98694
a way that could lead to ease the automation of the batch process using applescript droplet.

So I've followed the infos in the post but no luck, my coding really s**ks.

What this thread promises is very attractive to me if I can make it mine they say that by creating and apple script app, i would be able to drop videofiles onto the App and it should open VLC and transcode... much better than going through the wizard, type and clic all settings in and launch transcode x3000 video files :S

So ideally (my dream now!!) i'd love to do this or event better drop a folder on the app icon and have it outputted with the same files name in another folder in the new editable format!!

So if their is anyone familiar with apple scripts, please help, I think I'm almost there, it's probably the source and destination paths that I have wrong! PLEASE HELP!!

**Here is the bit of code they give:**

```
on open these_items
   try
      process_item(these_items)
   end try
end open

-- this sub-routine processes files 
on process_item(this_item)
   set full_path to the POSIX path of this_item
   do shell script "/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC" & " '" & full_path & "' --sout='#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,acodec=mp4a,ab=192}:standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=" & full_path & ".mp4}'"
end process_item
```

**And here is the script VLC gives me regarding my transcoding output files format:**

```
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=3072,acodec=mp4a,ab=256}:standard{mux=ts,dst=/Volumes/Untitled/EarthFreq_2013/EF2013_0132.ts,access=file}
```

**And here is what I'm trying to do (mixing both):**

```
on open these_items
    try
        process_item(these_items)
    end try
end open

-- this sub-routine processes files
on process_item(this_item)
    set full_path to the POSIX path of this_item
    do shell script "/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC" & " '" & volume/Macintosh HD/Users/GANDA/Desktop/sourcefolder & "' --sout='#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=3072,acodec=mp4a,ab=256}:standard{access=file,mux=ts,dst=" & volume/Macintosh HD/Users/GANDA/Desktop/destinationfolder & ".ts}'"
end process_item
```

I'm pretty sure i'm not so far.. but maybe Iam?? I'm a video editor, not a coder, i'd love to be able to understand some more, but please leave me a bit of time and i promise i'll get there before i die!!

Anyone understands me??
Tell me i'm not alone!

Peace

Noli

Answer (score 1):

Try pasting this to Terminal:

`cd ~/Desktop/sourcefolder; for f in *.mxf; do /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -I dummy "$f" --sout "#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=3072,acodec=mp4a,ab=256}:standard{mux=ts,dst=${f%mxf}ts,access=file}" vlc://quit; done`

This wouldn't re-encode the files:

```
for f in *.mxf; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy "${f%mxf}mkv"; done
```

It might not work with the corrupted files though. You can install ffmpeg with `brew install ffmpeg` after installing [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Comment: I just can't believe it!! YThis is working like a charme! You coders are the magician of the 3rd millenium!
I feel like an illiterate, I know I have to get into this now, possibly my first approach will be to participate to do bugg reports for and open source video editing software!!
YOU absolutely rock thank you!!
How can I help? You need videos to be done? my website: www.gandaprod.net

Comment: Always helpful is to accept the answer that solved your issue. You can also upvote answers / comments.

Comment: What is upvote answer? Sorry new to forum, but really keen on doing what it takes to rank you best!!